# Add column inside named matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have the following matrix:

```
m <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3, dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("w", "x", "y", "z")))
#   w x y  z
# a 1 4 7 10
# b 2 5 8 11
# c 3 6 9 12
```

How can I add a column with the values `c(13, 14, 15)` between column `x` and `y` *without knowing where `x` and `y` are*?

Using number ranges I know how to do this using `cbind`.

```
cbind(m[,1:2], c(13, 14, 15), m[,3:4])
#   w x    y  z
# a 1 4 13 7 10
# b 2 5 14 8 11
# c 3 6 15 9 12
```

For named columns, it'd be neat if I could supply the column ranges with `m[,:"x"]` and `m[,"y":]` of some sort, but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Additionally, if possible, giving that column its own header name during the insertion process would be nice.

EDIT: I should have specified that `x` and `y` always are in order, so adding the column after `x` would have been enough. Thanks for the more general answers as well!

Comment: I.e., `grep("x", colnames(m))` gives the index of the `x` to you. After that you can do your job with `cbind()` as you did.

Comment: `cbind(m, xx = 13:15)[, order(c(1:ncol(m), which(colnames(m) == 'x') + 0.1))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may found the columns positions by names and insert the new column properly:

```
x_pos <- which(colnames(m) == "x")
y_pos <- which(colnames(m) == "y")
m <- cbind(m[,1:x_pos], new=c(13, 14, 15), m[,y_pos:ncol(m)])
```

Answer (score 2):

When you can not assume that `x` comes before `y` and there is no need that they are following each without a gap you can try:

```
i <- seq_len(min(match(c("x", "y"), colnames(m))))
cbind(m[,i], v=c(13, 14, 15), m[,-i])
#  w x  v y  z
#a 1 4 13 7 10
#b 2 5 14 8 11
#c 3 6 15 9 12
```

In case they are ordered, that it will be enough to put it after *x* like:

```
i <- seq_len(match("x", colnames(m)))
cbind(m[,i], v=c(13, 14, 15), m[,-i])
```

Comment: I should have specified that `x` and `y` are in order. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly pretty but you can do this

```
cbind(m[,1:(which(dimnames(m)[[2]]=="x"))], 
      t=c(13, 14, 15),
      m[,(which(dimnames(m)[[2]]=="y")):dim(m)[2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `which` to find the desired column and assign a name in `cbind`, i.e.

```
cbind(m[, seq(which(colnames(m) == 'x'))], 
      w = c(13, 14, 15), 
      m[, (which(colnames(m) == 'y'):ncol(m))])

#  w x  w y  z
#a 1 4 13 7 10
#b 2 5 14 8 11
#c 3 6 15 9 12
```

Comment: Is there a reason you used `seq(which(...))` instead of `1:which(...)`?

Comment: For your case not really but in general it's 'safer' to use `seq()` instead of `n:n+...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function :

```
insert_a_column <- function(mat, first_col,second_col, new_col, vec) {
   #Get index of first column to match
   one <- match(first_col, colnames(mat))
   #Get index of second column to match
   two <- match(second_col, colnames(mat))
   #Add the middle column and combine the data
   new_mat <- cbind(mat[,1:one, drop = FALSE], vec, 
                    mat[, (one + 1):ncol(mat), drop = FALSE])
   #rename the new column
   colnames(new_mat)[one + 1] <- new_col
   #Return the matrix.
   return(new_mat)
}

insert_a_column(m, "x", "y", "a", c(13, 14, 15))

#  w x  a y  z
#a 1 4 13 7 10
#b 2 5 14 8 11
#c 3 6 15 9 12

insert_a_column(m, "y", "z", "a", c(13, 14, 15))
#  w x y  a  z
#a 1 4 7 13 10
#b 2 5 8 14 11
#c 3 6 9 15 12
```